# How to resolve Typescript type error in Firebase Functions after installing @google-cloud/storage

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions

I am receiving the following build error immediately after installing the Cloud Storage module to my Firebase Cloud Functions environment:

```
node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/service-object.d.ts(72,45): error TS8020: JSDoc types can only be used inside documentation comments.
node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/service-object.d.ts(72,45): error TS8028: JSDoc '...' may only appear in the last parameter of a signature.
node_modules/@google-cloud/common/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/oauth2client.d.ts(291,55): error TS1039: Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts.
```

Does anyone have any idea how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue seems to be related to installed Typescript versions ^2 and below. Upgrading to Typescript 3 resolved the issue for me.

Source: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/341

Comment: Check the package.json file to ensure that your installed Typescript version meet the minimum requirement. For example, nodejs-storage version 2.3.4 requires Typescript ~3.1.1

Comment: shit, firebase function auto generate typescript 2.8.3 causing error, thank you for your suggest